# Make a CanvasJS Chart using JSON data

Tags: javascript, html, canvasjs

I need to make this coding in a way where I can show JSON data in graph. but I don't know how to convert this coding in a way so that this graph will show JSON data. I am posting coding in here for your convenience.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>

    window.onload = function () {

    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
        animationEnabled: true,
        theme: "dark2",

        title:{
            text: "MOVEMENT CATEGORY"
              },

        subtitles:[
              {
            text: "(STANDSTILL, ON FOOT or ON VEHICLE)",

              },],

        axisX:{
            title: "TIME SLOT"
              },

        axisY:{
            title:"Number of users(%)",
            suffix: "%"
              },

        toolTip:
              {
            shared: true
              },

        data: [{
            type: "stackedArea100",
            name: "STANDSTILL",
            showInLegend: "true",
            yValueFormatString: "#,##0.##\"%\"",
            dataPoints: [
                { y: 83, label: "6am - 10am" },
                { y: 51, label: "10am - 4pm" },
                { y: 64, label: "4pm - 8pm" },
                { y: 71, label: "8pm - 12am" },
                { y: 45, label: "12am - 6am" }
            ]
        },
        {
            type: "stackedArea100",
            name: "ON FOOT",
            showInLegend: "true",
            yValueFormatString: "#,##0.##\"%\"",
            dataPoints: [
                { y: 20 , label: "6am - 10am" },
                { y: 30, label: "10am - 4pm" },
                { y: 24, label: "4pm - 8pm" },
                { y: 38, label: "8pm - 12am" },
                { y: 51, label: "12am - 6am" }
            ]
        },

        {
            type: "stackedArea100",
            name: "ON VEHICLE",
            showInLegend: "true",
            yValueFormatString: "#,##0.##\"%\"",
            dataPoints: [
                { y: 11, label: "6am - 10am" },
                { y: 61, label: "10am - 4pm" },
                { y: 50, label: "4pm - 8pm" },
                { y: 23, label: "8pm - 12am" },
                { y: 31, label: "12am - 6am" }
            ]
        }]
    });
    chart.render();

    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 600px; width: 100%;"></div>
    <script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What is the form of your JSON data?

Comment: [{"y1":83,"y2":20,"y3":11,"label":"6am – 10am"},{"y1":51,"y2":30,"y3":61,"label":"10am – 4pm"},{"y1":64,"y2":24,"y3":50,"label":"4pm – 8pm"},{"y1":71,"y2":38,"y3":23,"label":"8pm – 12am"},{"y1":45,"y2":51,"y3":31,"label":"12am – 6am"}]

Comment: I'm not sure of the problem. Your graph looks like this.. https://imgur.com/a/EVDlbMe.. which looks fine.

Comment: This code is fine for static data but it's not gonna run for json data! what are the changes I have to make in this code to run external json which will come from server. Any kind of help will be highly appreciable.

Comment: Ok, do you have a HTTP/AJAX request already coded somewhere? Even just an API that you intend to hit? Its easy enough to pass JSON data into ChartJS, but we need to know how it's returned. Is it 3 separate requests, or one big request containing all three datapoints?